# Using external music mp3 in flash game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

sorry for my english.
Im relative new to flash game development,
Im creating a game and I need some big size mp3 files.
If I add them into flash, .swf file will be too big.
I guess I need to host mp3 files somewhere and use URL Request?
Where can I upload mp3 files so they are always ready for use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to host mp3 files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the aim of your question, are you asking can you host and import or are you asking where should you host your files to import into your code.

Personally I'd recommend you compress the MP3 files, there is a good answer on another Stack Exchange which you can find [here](https://superuser.com/questions/84556/what-is-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-compress-a-mp3-file)

If you're looking to host your MP3 files I'd recommend [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) - it's free to download and you can easily upload/remove your files. You'll get a link to use in your code..

~ Will

Comment: I don't think hosting files with dropbox is a good idea, it has a fairly low bandwidth/request cap. Dropbox is really only useful for file synching across multiple PCs and among small groups but it's not useful for actually hosting files that are going to be accessed by many different people.